# How can I get several coordinates from a text file?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm setting up a script and I need to get some coordinates from a text file.

The architecture of my text file is:

```py
ABC;
 1 2
 6 -8;
DEF;
Coordinates
 3-5
 4 6
 9 7;
XYZ;
ABC;
Coordinates;
Coordinates
 1 2
 5 -1;
```

For the moment, I've tried to add the coordinates in a dictionary but only the last coordinates is seen. I've tried with a while loop as:

```py
file = open(txt, 'r')
line = file.readline()
while line:
   if line.lstrip().startswith('Coordinates') and not (line.rstrip().endswith(';')):
       coordinates['points'].append((x, y))
```

I have defined my X and Y points but I didn't find a way to add every coordinate into the dict.

The expected output:
`['points':[3, -5, 4, 6, 9, 7, 1, 2, 5, -1]]`

but for the moment, this is my output: `['points':[1, 2, 5, -1]]`

Comment: do you want coordinates to be a dict with one entry ("points") and a list of all the points?

Comment: @OmerBenHaim yes this is my goal

Comment: you are using append and yet you get only `[1, 2, 5, -1]`? weird, can you show us the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` for matching all number from regex.[(doc)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

I also use `map` to convert each number to `float` type. [(help on map)](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html)

Here the code:

```
# import module
import re
# Create output variable
res = {"Points": []}

# Read file
with open("temp.txt", "r") as f:
    # Read line
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        # Find begining block
        if "Coordinates" in line:
            # Read block
            while line and "Coordinates;" not in line:
                # Match numbers on line (with the - if negative)
                numbers = re.findall(r'(\-{0,1}\d+)', line)
                # If there are number
                if len(numbers) > 0:
                    # Add them as float
                    res["Points"] += map(float, numbers)
                    # Read next line
                line = f.readline()
        # Read next line
        line = f.readline()

print(res)
# {'Points': [3.0, -5.0, 4.0, 6.0, 9.0, 7.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, -1.0]}
```

Comment: The fact is, I'll update my question, in my text file it can be others numbers that I mustn't take in my dictionary.

Comment: Have a look at the update. I add an inner while to read blocks starting by `Coordinates` and ending by `Coordinates;`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I understood your issue, but I think that this piece of code will do the work :

```
with open(txt, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
output = {"points": []}
next_line_has_coords = False
for line in lines:
    text = line.strip()
    if next_line_has_coords:
        list_numbers = text.replace("-", " -").replace(";", "").split(" ")
        output["points"] += [int(number) for number in list_numbers if number != ""]
    if text.startswith("Coordinates") and not text.endswith(";"):
        next_line_has_coords = True
    if text.endswith(";"):
        next_line_has_coords = False
```